# Initialize sub matrix in a data frame using column names

Tags: r

I have a data frame (100 x 25) and I want to fill the sub-block [,19:25].
Is there a direct way to do this, using column names instead of '19:25'?
(without searching/matching column names or so...)

Comment: What is wrong with the `[,19:25]`?  If the columns are in the position mentioned, this is direct.

Comment: I don't see how you could subset based on column names without searching for them. Do you perhaps have column names "col1", "col2", "col3"...?

Comment: @akrun : absolutely nothing wrong with [,19:25] per se, but I have many columns that I can more easily 'remember' by name, so it seems more efficient to do 'a1':'c33' instead of searching the names, getting indices etc. That's a couple of lines of code. Ok, for you smarter guys maybe less. :)

Comment: @RomanLuštrik : the exact column names look like 'a1','b1','c1','a2','b2','c2','a3',...,'c24'  but maybe this cannot be done in R so you might have already answered my question. Thanks :)

Comment: @DusanKojic I posted a solution using `dplyr`.  Perhaps that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need

```
library(dplyr)
select(df, a1:c3)
#  a1 b1 c1 a2 b2 c2 a3 b3 c3
#1  6 19 13 19  2 14  7  5 10
#2  5  6  8  4 12  2  5 15  8
#3 15 16 14  1 15 12  8 13  6
#4 11 17 14 11  3 13  3 14  5
#5 14  6  7  3  5  1 19 20  1
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20, 30*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=30))
colnames(df) <-  paste0(rep(letters[1:3],10), rep(1:10,each=3))
```

Comment: Wow, 'dplyr' sounds exciting. I'm giving it a try ! Thnx !!